# SoapUI with Groovy Script calling multiple APIs

Tags: api, groovy, wsdl, soapui

I am using SoapUI with Groovy script and running into an issue when calling multiple APIs. In the system I am testing one WSDL/API handles the account registration, and returns an authenticator. I then use that returned authenticator to call a different WSDL/API and verify some information. I am able to call each of these WSDLs/APIs separate but when I put them together in a Groovy Script it doesn't work.

```
testRunner.runTestStepByName("RegisterUser");
testRunner.runTestStepByName("Property Transfer");

if(props.getPropertyValue("userCreated") == "success"){
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("AuthenticateStoreUser");
```

To explain the first line will run the TestStep "RegisterUser". I then do a "Property Transfer" step which takes a few response values from "RegisterUser" - the first is "Status" to see if it succeeded or failed, second is the "Authenticator". I then do an if statement to check if "RegisterUser" succeeded then attempt to call "AuthenticateStoreUser". At this point everything looks fine. Though when it calls "AuthenticateStoreUser" it shows the thinking bar then fails like a timeout, and if I check the "raw" tab for the request it says

```
<missing xml data>.
```

Note, that if I try the "AuthenticateStoreUser" by itself the call works fine. It is only after calling "RegisterUser" in the Groovy Script that it behaves strange. I have tried this with a few different calls and believe it is an issue calling two different APIs.

Has anyone dealt with this scenario, or can provide further direction to what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

*(I would have preferred to simply comment on the question, but I don't have enough rep yet)*

Have you checked the *Error log* tab at the bottom when this occurs? If so, what does it say and is there a stacktrace you could share?

Comment: Hi Arian, that is a good question. Though I had a power outage last night that ending in me losing my current project. While reconstructing the project this morning it seems to be working. I wish I could explain further or provide further insight into why it failed yesterday yet works today. If I am able to reproduce I will definately update... thanks